# Suggestion while Resume Writing - ability to grasp new concepts

Tags: resume

How can I mention it on my resume that I have a history of giving a nice performance with job duties of which I had no prior experience or knowledge.

For example, being an electronics engineer I had no knowledge of automobile engine technology but I did well in tasks involving knowledge of automobile technology.

Basically I want to send reader a message that I am not afraid of new things and can perform quite well.

Stucked on this: history of working well with new concepts

Comment: I think that readers of your resume may be able to tell that, given your Degree is on EE and that you list past jobs on other areas, you are well capable of that, no need to remark it.

Comment: [related question:](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/63972/how-do-i-emphasise-unusual-talents-in-an-application-or-interview/).

Comment: FYI.  To get better responses in the future, don't select a "best answer" so quickly.  People tend to stop providing additional answers when an answer is picked.  Try to wait until you get a few answers or at least a day or two before picking one as the best

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the saying goes, show don't tell.

> Successfully learned and implemented widget repair

or

> Took on additional responsibilities of learning and implementing widget maintenance

or

> Quickly and successfully learned thingamabob to take on additional expanded duties

Comment: Also, readers may be able to figure this themselves, given the OP lists his Degree and the jobs he has performed (and his reviews) that are evidently not related to the degree.

Comment: @GrayCygnus being a fast learner is something I have often conveyed, so I can relate to the Q.  Learned VBA in a week :D